# Problem with icacls on Windows 2003: "Acl length is incorrect"

Tags: windows-server-2003

I am confused by the output of icacls on Windows 2003. Everything appears to work on Windows 2008. I am trying to change permissions on a directory:

```
icacls . /grant mydomain\someuser:(OI)(CI)(F)
```

This results in the following error:

```
.: Acl length is incorrect.
.: An internal error occurred.
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files
```

The same command used on a file named "file" works:

```
icacls file /grant mydomain\someuser:(OI)(CI)(F)
```

Result is:

```
processed file: file
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know how to fix it, but why it happens is still unclear. Just issue

```
icacls . /resize
```

May be it is because that current folder ACL was not correctly propagated previously.

Comment: I'll try that. It happened on the root of drives, i.e. e:\ and similar on separate servers. I wonder why they would all not be correctly sized...